# How to determine if "http" is at the beginning of the text written with Java?

Tags: java, conditional-statements

I want to ask for a simple thing:
how to determine in a condition with Java `if TextField contains "http:// at the beginning of the text wrote`
I tried this code :

```
if(text1.getText().startsWith("http://") == null{
           //do something
 }
```

please can anybody help me and thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

```
if (text1.getText().startsWith("http://")) {
```

Comment: ohh! i forgot to update my question, but i want `if text1.getText() dosen't started with "http://" it should send a Dialog ` so how ican do that ?

Comment: Not enough detail to answer that. What do you mean `send` a dialog? - show? and what type? Android? Swing JavaFX, other? Best thing is to create a new question with all these details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what your asking but your if statement is looking to see if the boolean value that your return is null.  Which it won't ever be since its going to return either true or false.